# ubuntu PC is not accessible in VNC viewer in android

Tags: networking, server, android, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a PC, laptop and an android mobile. I have enabled my PC with WIFI connectivity and I am able to access it remotely in my laptop using Remmina(client). I have ubuntu installed on both my PC and and laptop.But when I am trying to access my PC(which is my server) from my android mobile using VNC viewer app. I am getting an error "The Authentication mechanism requested cannot be provided by computer". And when I try to access my laptop remotely I am able to see the screen. Both My PC and Laptop have same settings for desktop sharing. Please advise on how I can access my PC in my mobile to control it remotely.
Note: all popular ports are working through this PC onto my mobile. Eg: I am able to access my web applications on 80 and 8080 ports. I can do FTP to my PC from my mobile.

Answer (score 3):

The reason, as @CharlesBolin explained, is likely that the VINO connection is encrypted in a way it is not understood by your android app.

If that is the case, it is enough to type in the Ubuntu client:

`gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false`

(without sudo!) and restart the VNC server in order to disable the encryption on the Ubuntu server for the default VNC server shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Vino (the VNC server you are likely using in Ubuntu) require encryption by default, that unfortunately, virtually nothing else provides!

This page is one place that will tell you about it and how to fix it. Basically, you're just turning off the "require-encryption" option in Vino.

Comment: I think you missed the link on the page you refer !